# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds using pandas Series.from_csv

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am getting error as

```
  File "C:/Users/Toshiba/PycharmProjects/untitled1/stationarity.py", line 7, in <module>

    series = Series.from_csv('flowcaida.csv')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2640, in from_csv

    result = df.iloc[:, 0]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1325, in __getitem__

    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1662, in _getitem_tuple

    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 189, in _has_valid_tuple

    if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1597, in _has_valid_type
    return self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1638, in _is_valid_integer

    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

using this:

```
series = Series.from_csv('flowcaida.csv')
```

This is my data:

```
651680

459151

596299

474950

631421

465275

629861

455582

650192
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Series.from_csv` has been deprecated for quite a while now. You should be using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) instead.

Since you have a single column CSV, you can pass `squeeze=True` so that a `Series` is returned.

```
s = pd.read_csv(buf, header=None, names=["Data"], squeeze=True)
s

0    651680
1    459151
2    596299
3    474950
4    631421
5    465275
6    629861
7    455582
8    650192
Name: Data, dtype: int64

type(s)
pandas.core.series.Series
```